# PL/SQL: ORA 01422 fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am developing an order transaction where a user can order a product. Once they clicked the 'add to cart' button, it will be able to save on the database in how many times they want with the same order id. Order id is like a transaction id.

My problem is that whenever I want to display the items that customer ordered, it displays an error or ORA 01422. How can I resolve this error?

Here is my code

```
DECLARE 
  order_item_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  order_item_id := :MOTOR_PRODUCTS_ORDER.M_ORDERID;

  SELECT MOTOR_ID, 
         MOTOR_QTY_PURCHASED, 
         UNITPRICE
   INTO :MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS.MOTOR_ID, 
        :MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS.MOTOR_QTY_PURCHASED, 
        :MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS.UNITPRICE
   FROM MOTOR_ORDERS
  WHERE motor_order_id = order_item_id;

END;
```

Comment: [ORA-01422 Cause - You tried to execute a SELECT INTO statement and more than one row was returned.](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01422.php). The query returns 2 or more rows, but you cannot assing many values to scalar variable, so Oracle throws ORA 01422. Change the query. Scala variables like `:MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS.MOTOR_ID` can hold only scalar (single) value like 1, you cannot put many values like 1,2,3,4 into scalar variable.

Answer (score 0):

As krokodilo says, this error is caused because your query returns multiple rows. Depending on what you want to do, you have a couple of options.

If you want multiple values then either use a loop and process them one row at a time (if you are going to be performing a dml operation use bulk collect).  If you only want a single row then narrow your result set down with an extra where clause, or use MAX to ensure you only get one value back.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one row which will be returned from a query you'll need to use a cursor. One way to do this is with a cursor FOR loop:

```
DECLARE 
  order_item_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  order_item_id := :MOTOR_PRODUCTS_ORDER.M_ORDERID;

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT MOTOR_ID, MOTOR_QTY_PURCHASED, UNITPRICE
                 FROM MOTOR_ORDERS
                 WHERE motor_order_id = order_item_id)
  LOOP
    -- Do something here with the values in 'aRow'. For example, you
    -- might print them out:

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MOTOR_ID=' || aRow.MOTOR_ID ||
                         ' MOTOR_QTY_PURCHASED=' || aRow.MOTOR_QTY_PURCHASED ||
                         ' UNITPRICE=' || aRow.UNITPRICE);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Forms question; is it? If so, my suggestion is to let Forms do that job for you.

According to what you posted, there are two blocks:

- MOTOR_PRODUCTS_ORDER (a master block, form type)
- MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS (a detail block, tabular type)

I guess that there is a master-detail relationship between them. If there's none, I'd suggest you to create it. Although you can make it work *without* such a relationship, it'll be much more difficult. If you are unsure of how to do it, start from scratch:

- delete MOTOR_ORDER_ITEMS block (detail)
- create it once again, this time by following the Data Block Wizard
- Set MOTOR_PRODUCTS_ORDER to be its master block
- Relationship is on ORDER_ID column/item

Let's presume that by this point everything is set up. Retrieving items that belong to that ORDER_ID is now very simple:

- navigate to master block
- enter query mode
- enter value into an item that represents ORDER_ID
- execute query

End of story. Forms triggers & procedures (which were created by the Wizard) will do its job and retrieve both master and detail records.

No need for additional coding; if you're skilled developer, you can create such a form in a matter of minutes. Won't be *beautiful*, but will be effective & reliable.

There's really no use in doing it manually, although it is possible. Your code works if there's a single item for that ORDER_ID. For two or more items, as you already know, it'll fail with TOO-MANY-ROWS error.

Basically, if you insist, you should use a loop:

- you'd enter ORDER_ID into the master block
- as you need to move through the detail block, i.e. use NEXT_RECORD, which is a restricted procedure, you can't use number of triggers (open Forms Online Help System and read about them) so a "Show items" button (with its WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger) might be just fine
- a cursor FOR loop would be your choice
- for every row it fetches, you'd populate block items and
- navigate to next record (otherwise, you'd keep overwriting existing values in the 1st tabular block row)

As I said: possible, but not recommended.